# Optimized way of inserting Multiple records (User Defined Table Type VS C# Loop)

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-types

I want to find the optimized way for inserting multiple records in a Table from `Front End`. I have a Table like
`TableA(Id int,StudentId int,EntryTime DateTime,ClassId int,Status int)`.
On `Front End` i have a `DataGridView` in which a specific `Class` Students are loaded, for example 50 Students record is loaded in `DataGridView`. Now for saving all these `50 records` at once, i have `two methods` (I think so).
**Method 1**

I will create a `List` and assign all data from `DataGridView` to `List`, and then by using `ForEach` loop i will insert record one by one, by calling `Strored Procedure`. e.g in `C#`

```
  SqlComm.BeginTransaction();
  foreach (ClassName d in MyList)
  {
   .....
   .....
    SqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  SqlComm.CommitTransaction();
```

`MyList` is a `List` of a `User Defined Class`.

**Method 2:** 
 I will create a `DataTable` and pass all data from `DataGridView` to `DataTable` and in `Sql Server` i will create a `User-Defined Table Type` and then will use it as `argument` to `Stored Procedure`, and in `C#` i will pass the `DataTable` to `Stored Procedure`, and then in `Stored Procedure` i will `insert` record in Table. In `C#` like this..

```
SqlCommand SqlComm= new SqlCommand(sqlInsert, connection);
SqlParameter tvpParam = SqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@myType", myDataTable);
tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.TableATableType";

SqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**My Question** is that in above two methods which will be the `Best` way for inserting multiple records, which method will use less `Resources`..? Thanks

Comment: you can put the records of your list in a datatable and use BulkInsert to insert all the records at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `ExecuteNonQuery` requires a round trip to the server. On your local machine, you may not measure much overhead, but in *general* (assuming that your code to populate the table is reasonable, and the code using the table on the SQL side is also reasonable), I'd expect method 2 to be more efficient.

Also, generally, if you've not got any other code involving transactions, then the first method will have to create and commit 50 transactions, whereas the second should be able to run inside a single transaction, which should enable the file I/O costs to be lower also.